# Iframe stops working once screen size is less than 1200px.- Joomla 3 bootstrap3 template

Tags: css, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3, joomla3.0

I have build a construction website which has house images and plans from another site embedded in an I frame. I'm using Joomla 3.4 With bootstrap 3, It works fine until the screen size is below 1200px. it still views fine but nothings is clickable on a mobile device or if you change the size of the browser on a PC to below 1200px.

I have add a div to the out side of the iframe and gave it an ID of outerdiv  I then add the code below code as suggest by another site .

```
#outerdiv iframe {
position: absolute; /*-- I have also tried relative--*/
top:0;
left: 0;
width: 95%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

It now works as it should but it over lap other elements on the page. As soon as I add another div around it or add a class to the iframe  to keep it from overlapping other elements it stops being clickable again. Has anyone had this problem? If so could you please share how to overcome the issue

Thanks Darryn

Comment: Absolute positioning takes the element out of the document flow, and sets it "on top" of the other elements within the document. What might be happening is some other element with a transparent background is overlapping the iFrame making it unclickable. You could try relative positioning with a z-index: 100; or greater to see if it is clickable then.

Comment: Thanks Kyle I will try it and let you know .

Comment: Great stuff! Kyle  That fixed it. 100 wasn't enough, I made it 3000 and that has fixed the problem.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll try to write it up as an answer. :)

Comment: that should read 300 not 3000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as `position: absolute;` takes elements out of the document flow and effectively sets them "on top" of the other elements, what I suspect is happening in this scenario is that you have another element somewhere overlapping your `iframe` and so making it "unclickable."

If you set the element's position to relative and give it a high z-index number, it should set it "above" everything in the document and be clickable again.

```
iframe {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100; /*or higher*/
}
```